# Ruby on Rails: unit testing helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a simple helper method, which determines, whether a user should see the full price of a product or 0, based on his bonus points:

```
def show_user_price(product, user = current_user)
  return user.bonus_points == 100 ? 0 : product.full_price
end
```

Now I would like to unit test the method. I have created a new test in test/helpers/user_price_helper_test, which inherits from ActiveSupport::TestCase. I have included the UserProductHelper. The test case runs smoothly, all the assertions are passed, but in the end I get

```
Minitest::Assertion: Expected response to be <success>, but was <500>.
```

It seems the test runner evaluates the test as if it should return a template, or at least an HTTP response. How do I properly unit test helper methods like this one?

**Edit: my unit test method**

```
test 'user sees 0 price' do
  user = User.new(name: 'Sample user', bonus_points: 100)
  product = Product.new(name: 'Sample product', full_price: 200)
  result = show_user_price(product, user)
  assert result == 0
end
```

Comment: Can we see your unit test method?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: this message is from different test. probably controller test. please paste **whole** test output.

Comment: The Unit Test method you have posted does not match the error. It is not expecting `<success>` but is expecting `result` to be `0`. Please paste the whole / correct test output result.